# How do I extract an array of bits 2-9 from a bytearray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, binary, type-conversion

I have a 100,000 long bytearray, where every 16-bit line is a 10-bit address and 6-bit counts concatenated. I want to convert the 16-by-100,000 array into two separate (address and data) arrays in an array-wise, efficient manner. A short run-time is critical to my application.

What I have so far is

1. read binary into a uint16 array

```py
    f = open(curfile, mode="r")
    aint = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint16)
```

2. read each line inside a for-loop

```py
    line = '{0:15b}'.format(aint[nn])
```

3. extract integers from binary

```py
    addr[nn] = 2**8*return0ifempty(line[0]) + return0ifempty(line[1:9])
    count[nn] = line[-6:]
```

(return0ifempty returns 0 when ' ' is input)

The whole binary => uint16 => binary => uint16 idea is extremely inefficient. There must be a better way to do this. Are there any ways to truncate the array as in matlab, e.g., A(5:10,:)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want low 10 bits and high 6 bits:

```
low_10 = aint & 1023
high_6 = aint >> 10
```

If you want low 6 bits and high 10 bits:

```
low_6 = aint & 63
high_10 = aint >> 6
```

Unlike a Python loop, this is vectorised and runs much, much, much faster (also, no conversion to string).

EDIT: Looking at your example, you want 10 high for addr, and 6 low for count; so...

```
count = aint & 63
addr = aint >> 6
```

Some explanation for `63`: it is `0b111111`, so `& 63` will preserve 6 low bits and switch off any higher ones.